# form.cleaned_data in django is empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How can I debug the form.cleaned_data giving me None as a return? I am not sure which part of code should I share, but here is a snippet where I am validating the form and checking for cleaned data:

```
      if form.is_valid():              
            form.save()
            print(form.cleaned_data)
```

Output:

```
{'City': None, 'Country': None, 'Zip Code': None, 'ID': '43434'}
```

Comment: Exactly what is the problem here? If fields are not required, and the user does not fill in any data, then it will associate `None` with these fields.

Comment: So the fields are required and I am filling in data and submitting, the request.POST shows me data but when I do form.cleaned_data it doesn't show anything. So I am trying to understand why is it not showing me any thing when I do form.cleaned_data

Answer (score 0):

Check two things.

In the instantion of the form, you are passing both request.POST and request.FILES.

```
    if request.method == "POST":
      form = NewForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Ensure you call `form.is_valid()` before accessing `cleaned_data`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning.